# Procedure or function P_INSERT_T_INFORAMTION_SETING has too many arguments specified

Tags: vb.net

Thank you ahead of time for your help. It is much appreciated.

After two long hours of scouring Stack Overflow and other Google results for the reason that I am getting a "Procedure or Function has too many arguments specified," I have found no useful help. The reason for this is that everywhere, I read that I probably either have too many arguments specified, the incorrect names for my arguments, or the incorrect types. None of these are true to my case. Here is my code:

```
  USE [BANK_DB]
  GO
  /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[P_INSERT_T_INFORAMTION_SETING]       Script Date: 03/08/2017 03:15:35 ******/
  SET ANSI_NULLS ON
  GO
  SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
  GO



 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[P_INSERT_T_INFORAMTION_SETING]
 @CLIENT_CODECHECK  INT ,
 @ID_INFO  int OUTPUT
       ,@BANK_NAME  nvarchar(max) 
       ,@BANK_ADDRESS  nvarchar(max) 
       ,@MONEY_TYPE  nvarchar(max) 
       ,@LINCES_ID  nvarchar(MAX) 
       ,@TAX_ACCOUNTANT  nvarchar(MAX) 
       ,@EMPLOEE_NAME  nvarchar(max) 
       ,@BOSS_NAME  nvarchar(max) 
       ,@FLAG_RECOGNIZE  int 
      ,@START_TICKT_DATE  date 
        ,@END_TIKET_DATE  date 
       ,@SUBMIT_FLAG INT OUTPUT
       ,@BANK_NAME_EN nvarchar(max) 
       ,@FOREMAN_EMPLOYEE nvarchar(max) 
       ,@ASSOCIATE_Director nvarchar(max) 
 AS
 DECLARE 
 @C_MAX AS INT,
 @ACC_MAX AS INT    ,
 @C_COUNT INT
 BEGIN
 SET @SUBMIT_FLAG=0
 SET @C_COUNT=(SELECT COUNT(ID_INFO) FROM T_INFORMATION_SETTING WHERE ID_INFO=@CLIENT_CODECHECK)
 IF @C_COUNT>0
 BEGIN
 SET @SUBMIT_FLAG=0
 RETURN
 END
 set @ACC_MAX=(SELECT ISNULL(MAX(ID_INFO), 0)  FROM T_INFORMATION_SETTING) +1




       INSERT INTO [dbo].[T_INFORMATION_SETTING]
       ([ID_INFO]
       ,[BANK_NAME]
       ,[BANK_ADDRESS]
       ,[MONEY_TYPE]
       ,[LINCES_ID]
       ,[TAX_ACCOUNTANT]
       ,[EMPLOEE_NAME]
       ,[BOSS_NAME]
       ,[FLAG_RECOGNIZE]
        ,[START_TICKT_DATE]
       ,[END_TIKET_DATE]
       ,[BANK_NAME_EN]
       ,[FOREMAN_EMPLOYEE] 
       ,[ASSOCIATE_Director] )
 VALUES
       (@ACC_MAX   
       ,@BANK_NAME  
       ,@BANK_ADDRESS   
       ,@MONEY_TYPE   
       ,@LINCES_ID   
       ,@TAX_ACCOUNTANT  
       ,@EMPLOEE_NAME    
       ,@BOSS_NAME    
       ,@FLAG_RECOGNIZE 
       ,@START_TICKT_DATE
       ,@END_TIKET_DATE
       ,@BANK_NAME_EN
       ,@FOREMAN_EMPLOYEE
       ,@ASSOCIATE_Director
        )





   set @ID_INFO=@ACC_MAX


IF @@ERROR <>0
BEGIN
ROLLBACK
RETURN
END

SET @SUBMIT_FLAG=1

END
```

And here is the C# side of things:

```
  Private Sub BTN_SAVE_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles   BTN_SAVE.Click
    'Try
        If FROM_DATE.Text = TO_DATE.Text Then

        MessageBox.Show("ttt")
        Return

    End If

    If DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1 < 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("pleasr")
        Return
        Exit Sub
    End If



    If MsgBox("You sure to save", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo + MsgBoxStyle.Question, MSG_APP) = MsgBoxResult.No Then Exit Sub

    '   new_date.Value =
    ' DATE_SALE.Value.AddDays(Convert.ToInt32(My.Settings.DATE_END))
    Dim INSER_ED = New BANK_ACCOUNT.BANK_DBDataSetTableAdapters.QueriesTableAdapter
    INSER_ED.P_INSERT_T_INFORAMTION_SETING(-1, ID_INFO, My.Settings.BANK_NAME, My.Settings.ADDRESS, My.Settings.MONEY_TYPE, My.Settings.LINCES_ID, My.Settings.TAX_ACCOUNTANT, My.Settings.EMPLOEE_NAME, My.Settings.BOSS_NAME, 1, DATE_TIKCIT.Value, Convert.ToDateTime(DATE_TIKCIT.Value.AddDays(Convert.ToInt32(My.Settings.DATE_END))), 1, My.Settings.BANK_NAME_EN, My.Settings.FOREMAN_EMPLOYEE, My.Settings.ASSOCIATE_Director, FROM_DATE.Value, TO_DATE.Value)
    NUMBER_ACTION = ID_INFO
    Dim I As Integer

    For I = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim INSERTED = New BANK_ACCOUNT.BANK_DBDataSetTableAdapters.QueriesTableAdapter

        INSERTED.P_INSERT_T_CLIENTS(0, ID_CUSTOMER, DataGridView1.Rows(I).Cells(3).Value.ToString, DataGridView1.Rows(I).Cells(4).Value.ToString, Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView1.Rows(I).Cells(5).Value), DataGridView1.Rows(I).Cells(7).Value.ToString, DataGridView1.Rows(I).Cells(8).Value.ToString, Convert.ToDateTime(DataGridView1.Rows(I).Cells(9).Value), Convert.ToDateTime(DataGridView1.Rows(I).Cells(10).Value), DataGridView1.Rows(I).Cells(12).Value.ToString, 1, Convert.ToDecimal(DataGridView1.Rows(I).Cells(11).Value), Convert.ToDateTime(DataGridView1.Rows(I).Cells(6).Value), Convert.ToInt32(Val(My.Settings.START_NUM)), True, SUBMET_FLAG)
        Dim INS_DET = New BANK_ACCOUNT.BANK_DBDataSetTableAdapters.QueriesTableAdapter
        INS_DET.P_INSERT_T_DETAILS(ID_INFO, ID_CUSTOMER, SUBMIT_FLAG)
    Next


    If SUBMIT_FLAG = 1 Then

        MSG_SAVE()
        My.Settings.SAVE_FALGE = 0
        My.Settings.Save()
        DIFF_SAVE = 0
        Me.GET_MX_NUMBERTableAdapter.Fill(Me.BANK_DBDataSet.GET_MX_NUMBER)
        LBL_NUM.Text = Me.BANK_DBDataSet.GET_MX_NUMBER.Rows(0)(0)
        Button1_Click_1(Nothing, Nothing)
    Else

        MSG_ERROR()
    End If

    ' BTN_SAVE.Enabled = False
    ' Catch ex As Exception
    'MsgBox(ex.Message)
    'End Try
End Sub



Private Sub BTN_SAVE_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTN_SAVE.Click
    'Try
    If FROM_DATE.Text = TO_DATE.Text Then

        MessageBox.Show("")
        Return

    End If

    If DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1 < 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("test")
        Return
        Exit Sub
    End If



    If MsgBox("you sure to save?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo + MsgBoxStyle.Question, MSG_APP) = MsgBoxResult.No Then Exit Sub

    '   new_date.Value =
    ' DATE_SALE.Value.AddDays(Convert.ToInt32(My.Settings.DATE_END))
    Dim INSER_ED = New BANK_ACCOUNT.BANK_DBDataSetTableAdapters.QueriesTableAdapter
    INSER_ED.P_INSERT_T_INFORAMTION_SETING(-1, ID_INFO, My.Settings.BANK_NAME, My.Settings.ADDRESS, My.Settings.MONEY_TYPE, My.Settings.LINCES_ID, My.Settings.TAX_ACCOUNTANT, My.Settings.EMPLOEE_NAME, My.Settings.BOSS_NAME, 1, DATE_TIKCIT.Value, Convert.ToDateTime(DATE_TIKCIT.Value.AddDays(Convert.ToInt32(My.Settings.DATE_END))), 1, My.Settings.BANK_NAME_EN, My.Settings.FOREMAN_EMPLOYEE, My.Settings.ASSOCIATE_Director, FROM_DATE.Value, TO_DATE.Value)
    NUMBER_ACTION = ID_INFO
    Dim I As Integer

    For I = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim INSERTED = New BANK_ACCOUNT.BANK_DBDataSetTableAdapters.QueriesTableAdapter

        INSERTED.P_INSERT_T_CLIENTS(0, ID_CUSTOMER, DataGridView1.Rows(I).Cells(3).Value.ToString, DataGridView1.Rows(I).Cells(4).Value.ToString, Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView1.Rows(I).Cells(5).Value), DataGridView1.Rows(I).Cells(7).Value.ToString, DataGridView1.Rows(I).Cells(8).Value.ToString, Convert.ToDateTime(DataGridView1.Rows(I).Cells(9).Value), Convert.ToDateTime(DataGridView1.Rows(I).Cells(10).Value), DataGridView1.Rows(I).Cells(12).Value.ToString, 1, Convert.ToDecimal(DataGridView1.Rows(I).Cells(11).Value), Convert.ToDateTime(DataGridView1.Rows(I).Cells(6).Value), Convert.ToInt32(Val(My.Settings.START_NUM)), True, SUBMET_FLAG)
        Dim INS_DET = New BANK_ACCOUNT.BANK_DBDataSetTableAdapters.QueriesTableAdapter
        INS_DET.P_INSERT_T_DETAILS(ID_INFO, ID_CUSTOMER, SUBMIT_FLAG)
    Next


    If SUBMIT_FLAG = 1 Then

        MSG_SAVE()
        My.Settings.SAVE_FALGE = 0
        My.Settings.Save()
        DIFF_SAVE = 0
        Me.GET_MX_NUMBERTableAdapter.Fill(Me.BANK_DBDataSet.GET_MX_NUMBER)
        LBL_NUM.Text = Me.BANK_DBDataSet.GET_MX_NUMBER.Rows(0)(0)
        Button1_Click_1(Nothing, Nothing)
    Else

        MSG_ERROR()
    End If

    ' BTN_SAVE.Enabled = False
    ' Catch ex As Exception
    'MsgBox(ex.Message)
    'End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The error "Procedure or Function has too many arguments specified" should be clear enough - the proc has 16 parameters but your call to it has 18. Try removing the last 2 (FROM_DATE.Value, TO_DATE.Value) from the call.

Comment: I try removing (FROM_DATE.Value, TO_DATE.Value) from the call, but iam facing same the error